# Отображение чисел в другой диапазон

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, range

По одному приходят числа из диапазона `[0; N]`, при этом из приходящих чисел `M` различных, `M << N`. Как отобразить текущее пришедшее число в уникальное число из диапазона `[0; M-1]`?

По сути нужен хеш, уникально отображающий набор чисел в диапазон длины, равной количеству уникальных чисел в наборе.

Относительный порядок не важен, важно взаимно однозначное соответствие между `M` различных чисел и `[0; M-1]`, т.е. `0` не обязательно должен отображаться в `0` из диапазона, но обязательно в какое-то одно уникальное число.

Comment: Умножить на (N-1)/M... Если, грубо говоря, расстояние между числами не волнует - отсортировать и отобразить первое - на 0, второе - на 1, ...

Comment: Первое не 0, второе - на 1, третье... А потом, если важен порядок - отсортировать.

Comment: @Harry изменил вопрос

Comment: Второй раз изменение вопроса... Посмотрю завтра, может, к тому времени определитесь, что вам нужно-то...

Comment: @Harry уже определился

Comment: Если при отображении надо ещё и сохранять относительное расположение (если входящее больше, то и его отображение больше) - то задача нерешаема. Иначе - просто нумеровать (или случайно присваивать ещё не использованные номера из диапазона), запоминая имеющиеся числа и их отображения. Если запоминать нельзя - задача опять-таки нерешаема.

Comment: @Akina относительное расположение не важно. Почему без запоминания всех встретившихся чисел задача нерешаема?

Comment: Потому что входной словарь шире выходного, следовательно, отображение неоднозначно (двум разным входным просто обязано соответствовать одно и то же выходное), и при входящем втором из такой пары значении при уже имевшемся первом неминуема коллизия. Т.е. для того, чтобы задача была решаема, нужно иметь словарь входящих элементов - либо изначально полный, либо текущий.

Comment: @Akina так такой ситуации не может быть, потому что всего `M` различных

Comment: Удалил свой ответ, так как задача пока нормально не поставлена. Я отвечал на какую-то другую из версий вопроса.

Comment: @gbg что ненормального в задаче?

Comment: Вы ее  три раза переформулировали в течении 15 минут.

Comment: Список этих различных `M` - имеется? нет? тогда всего `N-K` различных, где K - количество уже обработанных.

Comment: @Akina не понял, причём тут уже обработанные. Сколько бы много чисел не приходило, и из какого широкого диапазона они не были, если среди них только `M` различных, то эти `M` различных можно уместить в диапазон `[0; M-1]` теоретически. Как это сделать практически непонятно только

Comment: Ну так я ж уже сказал - либо изначально должен быть известен список этих различных М, либо их надо накапливать по мере приёма вместе с присвоенными им отображениями. Если ни то, ни другое недоступно, задача нерешаема.

Comment: @Akina *Если ни то, ни другое недоступно, задача нерешаема* -- **почему**?

Comment: Я уже объяснял. По причине наличия коллизий на неопределённом наборе.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант решения данной проблемы со словарем:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

using Dict = unordered_map<size_t, size_t>;

class CoDec
{
    Dict dict;
public:
    size_t code(const size_t in)
    {
        //ищем в словаре
        const auto pos = dict.find(in);
        if(pos==dict.end())
        {
            //если не нашли, пополняем словарь
            //присваиваем новый код, равный прошлой длине словаря;
            const size_t cnt=dict.size();
            return dict[in] = cnt;
        }            
        return pos->second; //если нашли, просто выдаем словарное значение
    }
    size_t decode(const size_t in) const
    {
        //выдаем из словаря нужное значение по коду
        return find_if(dict.cbegin(), dict.cend(), [&in](const Dict::value_type& a)
        {
            return in == a.second;
        })->first;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    CoDec cdc;
    cout << cdc.code(2)  <<' '<< cdc.code(5)   <<' '<< cdc.code(8)  <<' '<< cdc.code(5)  << endl ;
    cout << cdc.decode(0)<<' '<< cdc.decode(1) <<' '<< cdc.decode(2)<<' '<< cdc.decode(1)<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/RP56uB)